# Why my class is not added to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add a class to a js generated paragraph, but it does not work. I have also tried to add style directly to the DOM element, but neither does this work. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var dataCurent = new Date();
var minut = dataCurent.getMinutes();
var vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function ParagrafNou() {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(10, minut); i++) {
    var index = Math.random(vector);
    var paragraf = document.createElement('p');
    var continut = document.createTextNode('Ilie Andrei-Virgil ');
    paragraf.style.fontSize = 'xxx-large';
    if (index == 1)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa1');
    if (index == 2)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa2');
    if (index == 3)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa3');
    if (index == 4)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa4');
    if (index == 5)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa5');
    document.body.appendChild(paragraf.appendChild(continut));
  }
}

ParagrafNou()
```

```css
.clasa1 {
  color: red;
}

.clasa2 {
  color: blue;
}

.clasa3 {
  color: green;
}

.clasa4 {
  color: black;
}

.clasa5 {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add the text to the paragraph and then add the paragraph to the body
2. Your index was not an int
3. Your random also needed fixing

```js
var dataCurent = new Date();
var minut = dataCurent.getMinutes();
var vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function ParagrafNou() {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(10, minut); i++) {
    var index = vector[Math.floor(Math.random() * vector.length)];
    var paragraf = document.createElement('p');
    var continut = document.createTextNode('Ilie Andrei-Virgil ');
    paragraf.style.fontSize = 'xxx-large';
    if (index == 1)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa1');
    if (index == 2)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa2');
    if (index == 3)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa3');
    if (index == 4)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa4');
    if (index == 5)
      paragraf.classList.add('clasa5');
      paragraf.appendChild(continut)
    document.body.appendChild(paragraf);
  }
}

ParagrafNou()
```

```css
.clasa1 {
  color: red;
}

.clasa2 {
  color: blue;
}

.clasa3 {
  color: green;
}

.clasa4 {
  color: black;
}

.clasa5 {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` will return a value between 0 inclusive but not 1 which is not the index you are using in the next if statements.

In order to get a random index from `vector` array, you should use:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * vector.length);
```